# Find way for gathering data and replace with values from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for an Oracle SQL query to find a specific pattern and replace them with values from another table.

Scenario:

Table 1:

```
No      column1
-----------------------------------------
12345  user:12345;group:56789;group:6785;...
```

Note: field 1 may be has one or more pattern

Table2 :

```
Id     name       type
----------------------
12345  admin      user
56789  testgroup  group
```

Result must be the same

```
No        column1
-----------------------------------
12345     user: admin;group:testgroup
```

Comment: Why PLSQL? Isn't a plain SQL query good? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: My db is oracle and i can just operate on them

Comment: PLSQL is the Oracle procedural  extension for SQL. If you need a SQL query working for Oracle, you would better tag Oracle and SQL, not PLSQL. Also, please post what you tried/searched so far

Comment: I looking some guys advise to use select decode,some select with regex_substr or regex_replace , all of that working with pointer . I want replace all pattern match not one of pointer at pattern and also i tested with for but not working

Comment: Some hints: you first need to split your `column1` value. A search like "oracle split string" would be enough. Then you have to remove the `'user:'` and `'group:'` parts ( and this should be easy)  and jojn this result with the `table2`. After this, you should have one row for every user/group and a `LISTAGG` should do the work to build again one row for `No`. Please try some code and then, if you have an issue with your code, feel free to post a question here.

Comment: I seprate values in a view same this no,name1,value1    values(12345,user,12345)  for this solution i must find a solution same as loop for checking values_[1-9] AND replace them with name from another table when id equal value[1-9] . Is not fear i create a lot of view and combine that togheter as a view

Comment: You don't need a loop, you can simply join your splitted values with table2

Comment: I seprate they . First i need to gather values from table2 and save in another view . One way is create 9 seprate viewes . I looking solution for do all of that . Also i tested with select case when vlues_id=id then replace(name) end . But when i mention values_2 till 9 it's just gather first column and replace from table2

Answer (score 0):

**Logic:**

- First split the concatenated string to individual rows using `connect
  by` clause and regex.
- Join the newly created table(split_tab) with Table2(tab2).
- Use `listagg` function to concatenate data in the columns.

**Query:**

```
WITH tab1 AS
     ( SELECT '12345' NO
             ,'user:12345;group:56789;group:6785;' column1
        FROM DUAL )
    ,tab2 AS
     ( SELECT 12345 id
             ,'admin' name
             ,'user' TYPE
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 56789 id
            ,'testgroup' name
            ,'group' TYPE
        FROM DUAL )
SELECT no
      ,listagg(category||':'||name,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tab2.id) column1
  FROM ( SELECT    NO
                  ,REGEXP_SUBSTR( column1, '(\d+)', 1, LEVEL ) id
                  ,REGEXP_SUBSTR( column1, '([a-z]+)', 1, LEVEL ) CATEGORY
              FROM tab1
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count( column1, '\d+' ) ) split_tab
      ,tab2
 WHERE split_tab.id = tab2.id
 GROUP BY no
```

**Output:**

```
No     Column1
12345  user:admin;group:testgroup
```

Comment: query is not optimized ,  CPU  increased to 100% and oracle cannot response to another queries after run

Comment: I have hug data and you tested according to sample

Comment: @user3728800 check the plan of the query and see how it can be optimized for your data

Answer (score 0):

```
with t1 (no, col) as 
(
  -- start of test data
  select 1,   'user:12345;group:56789;group:6785;' from dual union all
  select 2,   'user:12345;group:56789;group:6785;' from dual
  -- end of test data
)
  -- the lookup table which has the substitute strings
  -- nid : concatenation of name and id as in table t1 which requires the lookup
  -- tname : required substitute for each nid
, t2 (id, name, type, nid, tname) as
(

  select t.*, type || ':' || id, type || ':' || name from 
  (
    select 12345 id,  'admin' name,      'user' type from dual union all
    select 56789,  'testgroup',  'group' from dual 
  ) t
)
--select * from t2; 
-- cte table calculates the indexes for the substrings (eg, user:12345)
-- no : sequence no in t1
-- col : the input string in t1
-- si : starting index of each substring in the 'col' input string that needs attention later
-- ei : ending index of each substring in the 'col' input string
-- idx : the order of substring to put them together later
,cte (no, col, si, ei, idx) as
(
  select no, col, 1, case when instr(col,';') = 0 then length(col)+1 else instr(col,';') end, 1 from t1 union all
  select no, col, ei+1, case when instr(col,';', ei+1) = 0 then length(col)+1 else instr(col,';', ei+1)  end, idx+1 from cte where ei + 1 <= length(col)
)
,coll(no, col, sstr, idx, newstr) as
(
  select 
    a.no, a.col, a.sstr, a.idx, 
    -- when a substitute is not found in t2, use the same input substring (eg. group:6785)
    case when t2.tname is null then a.sstr else t2.tname end 
  from 
    (select cte.*, substr(col, si, ei-si) as sstr from cte) a 
    -- we don't want to miss if there is no substitute available in t2 for a substring
    left outer join 
    t2 
    on (a.sstr = t2.nid)
)
select no, col, listagg(newstr, ';') within group (order by no, col, idx) from coll
group by no, col;
```